# setTimeout() no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

estoy haciendo una función onclick para animar una imagen y pasado un tiempo desanimarla, pero a la hora de ejecutar el setTimeout, no funciona.
Adjunto el código debajo.
Por cierto, el onclick esta en el html, no se si influira

```
var times = 0;

//que la imagen se mueva
function animate(imagen) {
    imagen.src="../fotos/saludar.gif";
    console.log("Animate")
}

//que la imagen no se mueva
function inanimate(imagen) {
    imagen.src="../fotos/panda.png";
    console.log("Inanimate")
}

//fucnion principal
function easterEgg() {
    let img = document.querySelector("#panditalogo")
    console.log(times);
    times++;

    if (times == 15){   
        animate(img)
        /* let time =  */setTimeout(inanimate(img), 3000);
        times = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: debe ser por el paso de parametros a la función inanimate, intentalo así `setTimeout(inanimate,3000,img)`

Answer (score 2):

El comentario de @soyunewok es correcto. El motivo por que que no te funciona es que

```
inanimate(img)
```

Es una llamada a la función inanimate. Es decir, la estás ejecutando, no pasándosela a setTimeout().

El resultado devuelto por esa función es pasado a setTimeout() para que lo ejecute cuando se cumpla el tiempo. Como tu función no devuelve nada, setTimeout() no ejecuta nada. Si inanimate(img) devolviera una función, setTimeout() la ejecutaría.

Aparte de la solución propuesta por @soyunewok, podrías poner algo como

```
setTimeout(function() { inanimate(img); }, 3000);
```

En este caso le estás pasando a setTimeout() una función anónima que ejecuta la llamada a tu función cuando se cumpla el tiempo.

Comment: Gracias, lo conseguí solucionar de esa forma

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu función `easterEgg()` de la siguiente manera (lee los comentario):

```
// fucnion principal
function easterEgg() {
    let img = document.querySelector("#panditalogo");
    console.log(times);
    times++;

    if (times == 15){   
        animate(img)
        // setTimeout(inanimate(img), 3000);
        // el parámetro img debe ir como otro argumento de setTimeout()
        setTimeout(inanimate, 3000, img);
        times = 0;
    }
}
```

También puedes intentar lo siguiente y te va funcionar igual.

```
// fucnion principal
function easterEgg() {
    let img = document.querySelector("#panditalogo")
    console.log(times);
    times++;

    if (times == 15){   
        animate(img)
        // debes llamar a una función sin parámetros (pasándole una función anónima)
        setTimeout(function(){ inanimate(img); }, 3000);
        times = 0;
    }
}
```

Eso sería todo, espero haberte ayudado.